# Android button changing color on second time clicked

Tags: android, button, background

I am making a game that changes the color and backgrounds of buttons. When the app opens I run the newGame function. Then after the game ends, to replay the game I recall the newGame function again. However, every time the game is replayed, when a button is clicked, it turns orange for a second before doing what it is supposed to do.

```
fun newGame() {
        allButtons.forEach {
            it.text = ""
            it.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default)
            it.isEnabled = true
        }
        gameInProgress = true
}
```

At other points in the code I'll change the background or enabled property of the buttons using some of the following lines code

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.zeroColor)
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flag)
button.isEnabled = false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is problem?

Comment: Do you have single button or multiple? also more code would be helpful to solve problem.